# Bolasso in R, or other model selection techniques for parametric models

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model-selection

I can't find any packages which allow me to implement bolasso in R, does anyone know of one?

Otherwise, I am interested in model selection techniques which can be implemented in R for logistic models.

My sole concern is predictive ability. The data has many covariates (or features) and I would like to investigate up to 3rd or even 4th level interactions and 2nd order terms, this is several thousand covariates (there are ~200k observations) so it is important that the techniques are fast.

Comment: The [SparseLearnerPackage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseLearner/SparseLearner.pdf) also has bolasso implemented. An example is given [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SparseLearner/versions/1.0-2/topics/Bolasso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package mht does seem to contain facilities for running a bolasso analysis in R. Alas, the package has been archived, and is not available for the current release (3.0.1) as, e.g., a Windows binary.

However, past versions are available from, e.g.:

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mht/mht_2.011.tar.gz
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/mht_2.011.zip

If you can compile the package yourself (modifications of the package might be required) or you still have access to R 2.14, you can use the packages from these urls.